# File upload with postman with pre-signed url not working

Tags: curl, amazon-s3, postman

I am trying to upload a file using postman. I have attached the file by clicking "body" (in postman) -> binary -> choose file. I use S3 to upload with pre-signed urls. In the url, the name of the file is exactly the same as the name of the file I select in postman. When running the request, I get an error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
    <Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>
    <AWSAccessKeyId>...</AWSAccessKeyId>
    <StringToSign>PUT

text/plain
1551977056
x-amz-acl:private
/wiivv-staging-private-storage/measurement/6506684788010901504/1551405460831/topLeft-2.jpeg</StringToSign>
    <SignatureProvided>...</SignatureProvided>
    <StringToSignBytes>...</StringToSignBytes>
    <RequestId>DB2FC5FE064CF49A</RequestId>
    <HostId>zbsLj7mcuXJa8D9JX1jFN1Lo+lI02/EvJreAXmPQjPezmU1sucQamXuqlGoUBzAq3nAaejx3doA=</HostId>
</Error>
```

However by exporting the postman request (by clicking on "code") to get a curl command I get:

```
curl -X PUT \
  '[s3-presigned-url]' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: 84700b0d-0cd2-4de5-b52c-7de39a12253e' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache'
```

And adding an additional option for uploading the file:

```
curl -X PUT \
  '[s3-presigned-url]' \
  -H 'Postman-Token: 84700b0d-0cd2-4de5-b52c-7de39a12253e' \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache'
  --upload-file ~/topLeft-2.jpeg
```

it worked!

In summary, in postman, it doesn't work and the same request exported in curl with the addition of the `--upload-file` option, it does...

How can I make the request work with postman?

EDIT 1:
Looks like it is related to the bug https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/2521 where postman automatically add a `Content-Type: text/plain` header even though no headers were provided.

EDIT 2:
here a screen shot of the postman console. See the unwanted `content-type` header?
[image]
But you can't see that header if you toggle the `Pretty` output:
[image]

EDIT 3:
using "content-type: multipart/form-data", I get

```
PUT /measurement/6506684788010901504/1551405460831/topLeft-2.jpeg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIKNR3HJGZI24MDTQ&Expires=1554393626&Signature=OaqaUqB2%2B3jp2AH97aWKujV3ZD8%3D&x-amz-acl=private
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------092560820091438222667657
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: e45247b4-0fc4-4adb-8e7b-effb82dc8e73
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.6.1
Accept: */*
Host: wiivv-staging-private-storage.s3.amazonaws.com
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate
content-length: 199703

name=topLeft-2.jpegfilename=[object Object]

HTTP/1.1 403
status: 403
x-amz-request-id: 640967A618ABD4A0
x-amz-id-2: IVZtpEDxEEo0R7JaQWrsOi8/6UESbKH4dZNWDnwJDJBhv1ppZx56cvMPt6xT4ZJ3qWiFernsu54=
Content-Type: application/xml
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Thu, 04 Apr 2019 15:58:34 GMT
Connection: close
Server: AmazonS3
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message><AWSAccessKeyId>AKIAIKNR3HJGZI24MDTQ</AWSAccessKeyId><StringToSign>PUT multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------------092560820091438222667657 1554393626 x-amz-acl:private /wiivv-staging-private-storage/measurement/6506684788010901504/1551405460831/topLeft-2.jpeg</StringToSign><SignatureProvided>OaqaUqB2+3jp2AH97aWKujV3ZD8=</SignatureProvided><StringToSignBytes>50 55 54 0a 0a 6d 75 6c 74 69 70 61 72 74 2f 66 6f 72 6d 2d 64 61 74 61 3b 20 62 6f 75 6e 64 61 72 79 3d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 2d 30 39 32 35 36 30 38 32 30 30 39 31 34 33 38 32 32 32 36 36 37 36 35 37 0a 31 35 35 34 33 39 33 36 32 36 0a 78 2d 61 6d 7a 2d 61 63 6c 3a 70 72 69 76 61 74 65 0a 2f 77 69 69 76 76 2d 73 74 61 67 69 6e 67 2d 70 72 69 76 61 74 65 2d 73 74 6f 72 61 67 65 2f 6d 65 61 73 75 72 65 6d 65 6e 74 2f 36 35 30 36 36 38 34 37 38 38 30 31 30 39 30 31 35 30 34 2f 31 35 35 31 34 30 35 34 36 30 38 33 31 2f 74 6f 70 4c 65 66 74 2d 32 2e 6a 70 65 67</StringToSignBytes><RequestId>640967A618ABD4A0</RequestId><HostId>IVZtpEDxEEo0R7JaQWrsOi8/6UESbKH4dZNWDnwJDJBhv1ppZx56cvMPt6xT4ZJ3qWiFernsu54=</HostId></Error>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alright for whoever comes to that issue, here is how I fixed it. In our app logic we now pre signed the url with a given content type of type application/octet-stream (I don't think it does really matter, what matters is to overwrites the "text/plain" that is automatically added by the postman desktop app ) and we send the specified content-type with the postman request.

```
let s3Param = {
  Bucket: this.bucketName,
  Key: filePath,
  Expires: bucketConfig.uploadExpireInSecond,
  ACL: bucketConfig.acl,
  ContentType: 'application/octet-stream',
};

s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', s3Param, ...);
```

and in the postman request headers we have "Conent-Type: application/octet-stream"

Answer (score 1):

Either your point of bug in Postman is correct or you're missing the file name in the 1st step that's why Signature Mismatch error. I faced this scenario of Signature Mismatch when I was not passing filename to upload and "assumed" that the filename on my machine will be used on S3. That was not the case.

**EDIT**

The content-type should be multipart/form-data and NOT plain-text. You can use name="filename" while uploading file as shown in below sample.

```
PUT  HTTP/1.1
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 98317a86-3352-48f6-bff0-e25413cb56dd
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="status.png"; filename="/Desktop/status.png
```

Comment: I'll try again and make sure I am not missing the file.

Comment: You might be right. Nowhere do I state the filename. I assumed by selecting the file from postman, it would use that as the filename. How would you suggest I pass the filename?

Comment: I tried, didn't work either, I added the raw request and response as it is shown in the postman console (EDIT 3).